# Slick 2 Convert (Column[A], Column[B]) to Column[(A,B)]

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

Using Slick 2, I am trying to generate a query with a tupled IN clause:

```
select * from my_table where (a, b) IN ((1, 87));
```

Given:

```
val seq: Seq[(Int, Long)]

val a: Column[Int]
val b: Column[Long]
```

I am trying to generate the query along the lines:

```
(a, b) inSetBind seq
```

This doesn't work as `(a,b)` is of type `(Column[Int], Column[Long])` and not `Column[(Int,Long)]`. Is it possible to convert this? There used to be a ~ operator in Slick 1 that did something similar but that appears gone in version 2.

Answer (score 1):

Currently not supported. Workaround in here: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/995